# On demand revalidation without webhook?

Tags: next.js

What I want is to do an on-demand revalidation on a click of a button WITH the secret key enabled. However it is not recognizing my .env secret token (saying it is undefined) when I call it like this:

.env

```
MY_SECRET_TOKEN = "1234"
```

/api/revalidate

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.query.secret !== process.env.MY_SECRET_TOKEN) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' })
  }

  try {
    await res.revalidate('/path-to-revalidate')
    return res.json({ revalidated: true })
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating')
  }
}
```

index.js

```
export default function Home({time{) {
   function revalidate() {
      fetch('/api/revalidate?secret=${process.env.MY_SECRET_TOKEN}`) 
   } //THIS WILL NOT FETCH ANYTHING.
  
   console.log(`${process.env.MY_SECRET_TOKEN}`) //THIS WILL RETURN 1234

   return (
     <h1> {time} 
     <button onClick={() => revalidate()}> Revalidate </button>
     </h1>
   )
}
```

However, calling it directly on the web : https://localhost:3000//api/revalidate?secret=1234 works fine.

If I don't add a MY_SECRET_TOKEN in .env AND only fetch (/api/revalidate) it will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side env variable [must be prefixed](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) `NEXT_PUBLIC_`

In your .env file, you should have a client-side variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_SECRET_TOKEN` and a server-side `MY_SECRET_TOKEN`

Comment: Just so I got this right: .env should have a : NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_SECRET_TOKEN and MY_SECRET_TOKEN with the same 1234 code? Should I change the revalidate and index file to point to NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_SECRET_TOKEN? Or leave as is.

Comment: The two env values need to match because your code is checking if they match.  The client-side code (your page code) must use the prefixed env version. Your server code (API route) shouldn't use the prefixed version.